# Datalist search on all words

Tags: html, html-datalist

I have implemented a datalist in my project and it works. However my issue can be seen in this simple tutorial. If you type *Explorer*, why does it not find *Internet Explorer*?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `<datalist>` is different in different browsers. Some will search for a substring, and some will only search for an initial substring (like in the case you are describing).